# Run a selenium script with a GUI on a remote server

Tags: linux, ssh, selenium-chromedriver

I have a linux (Machine A) and a Windows (Machine B) device.

I have created a Python Selenium script that uses Chromedriver and does some automation with a GUI - this script is stored on Machine B.

My ideal situation is to use Machine A (linux) to be able to SSH into Machine B (windows), run the script, and display the Chrome GUI on Machine B.

Running the following command on my linux machine will nearly produce the result that I want: `ssh '<MachineB@ip>' 'powershell < ./.../run.bat'`
(this run.bat contains only `python ./path/to/script/script.py`)

[Script is clearly running and chrome processes are running in the background on Machine B](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oCMFl.png)
But... there is no GUI opening on Machine B.

How can I change this so that the GUI will open on the Windows machine?